# Reducing Clock Cycle Count in While Loop for Granularity

Tags: c, performance, while-loop, msp430

I have a `while` loop implemented in C for an MSP430 processor that currently looks like this:

```c
register unsigned int sw_loop_count = 0U;
...

while (TACCL0 & CCIE)
{
    ++sw_loop_count;
}

...
#pragma vector=TIMERA0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A(void)
{
    // Disable the timer interrupt flag and enable.
    TACCTL0 &= ~CCIFG;
    TACCTL0 &= ~CCIE;
}
```

I'm using this loop for calibration purposes, the context of which I don't think matters too much for my question. I've calculated that each iteration of the loop, including the check `TACCL0 & CCIE` takes 11 clock cycles. For purposes of granularity, I would really like to get this number as low as possible, and programmatically if possible. I might be being a complete moron, but I can't think of a way of reducing the cycle count for the loop, so any advice would be appreciated. I need the `sw_loop_count` value, one way or another.

Comment: Run this through the compiler with an ASM output and see what *exactly* has the compiler done to your loop. Maybe there's something you can optimize on the assembler level? In that case you can just insert and ASM block into your C code after you are done fiddling with it. Although in your case I suspect that both TACCL0 and CCIE are `volatile` so you have to ensure they are being read from memory (not CPU) every time and you can hardly reduce that time...

Comment: Have you considered another mechanism for measuring performance? Perhaps grab time before and after the `while()` and just leave the loop empty '{}`? This would remove the time to do the increment instruction and could reduce your cycles.

Comment: this may also be optimized out by a compiler... ;-)

Comment: @YePhIcK: TACCL0 and CCIE cannot be `volatile`. TACCL0 and CCIE are special function registers, not C variables. They can't be read from memory since they aren't *in* memory. They must be read from CPU because that's the only place they should ever be.

Comment: Oh, then my answer below is not entirely correct :) But mostly correct - it should (in theory) reduce the number of CPU cycles to execute your `while()` loop

Comment: @Mike: The `sw_loop_count` is needed, since that value gives me a calibrated timer value. A bit of context, as maybe it is useful: I'm running an accurate 4MHz crystal as the timer source for a duration of 1ms and counting internal clock cycles (clocked off a 1MHz DCO) that occur in this time (a factor of `sw_loop_count`. This gives me a calibrated timer value for future use with the DCO. In other words, I think I need the increment in some fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, after I put a comment I realized that there *may be* something you can do ;-) In your `while()` condition you are checking *two* values. From the looks of it both those values *must* be defined as `volatile` so that they are ready from memory every single time they are used...

Can you reduce those two into a single one? Have your interrupt handler do the necessary comparison and set a *single* flag that you will be checking in your loop.

Or you can get really fancy and do it *another way around*, like that:

```
// signed and global (or you can pass it's address into your interrupt's routine)
volatile signed int sw_loop_count = 0;
```

Then there's your "measurement" loop:

```
while(++sw_loop_count) {}
```

and in your interrupt routine:

```
if(TACCL0 & CCIE)
{
  real_count = sw_loop_count; // save the value for future use before we destroy it
  sw_loop_count = -1; // this will turn into 0 in that while's pre-increment, ending the loop
}
```

OTOH... introducing the `volatile` may get so much hit from memory access that it may in fact *slow down* the `while()` loop. It really does all depend on your actual architecture (down to what type of memory controller and cache controllers there are) and I still maintain that you may be better off running it through an assembler mode and looking at what the compiler is doing.

Comment: The time I use in the interrupt routine isn't actually of too much concern, as I've got the value I need by this point, so this might actually work. I've looked at the disassembly, which shows that the clock cycles for the increment and jump is 6, so this will give me quite a saving. I haven't actually got much optimisation on at the moment, so this could save me even more. I'll try it tomorrow and get back to you, thanks.